# How to execute contract methods without metamask confirmations?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I would like to know if there is a way to execute my contract methods without requiring the confirmation of metamask.

I found something `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` but can't seem to figure out how to use it and what to send in it.

New here! Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confirmation of metamask is actually asking you if you want to sign this transaction with your private key. I find Metamask user friendly, but it's for a bit more technical people and normal users will need some time until they get used with it. Anyway if you want to achieve raw transaction submitting to blockchain you can use this library [ethereumjs-tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-tx). Check the example inside of how you sign your raw transaction and you can continue this way:

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + tx.serialize(), function (err, transactionHash) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else{
        console.log(transactionHash);
    }
});
```

Comment: Let's consider this...
```function addFile(string memory _name, address _address) onlyOwner public payable
    {
        fileCount++;
        files[fileCount] = File(fileCount,_name,owner,_address);
        emit ProductCreated(fileCount, _name, owner, _address);
    }
```
and my function call is 
```viewFile(id)
  {this.setState({loading: true});
    this.state.marketplace.methods.viewFile(id).send({from: this.state.account})
}
```

Then how will this be?

Comment: If you want to use web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction for other stuff than sending ethers to other address, you have to do this txParams.data = <YOUR_CONTRACT_INSTANCE>.methods.<SMART_CONTRACT_METHOD>(<SMART_CONTRACT_METHODS>).encodeABI();

Comment: txParams.data is the abi defenition of your smart contract method.

Comment: okay Thanks that was exactly what I was trying to figure out